# how to add a button that cancels the timer? powershell

Tags: powershell, winforms

Essentially what iam planing on doing with this script is that the user executes it and then it shows a window that says" the computer will restart in x seconds" he then has the option to cancel this or execute it now. But i cant seem to figure out how to make the cancel button clickable. If this has already been answered somehwere pls give me a link to it.

```
# Load the required assemblies
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

# Create a Form
$Counter_Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Counter_Form.Text = "Countdown Timer"
$Counter_Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800, 350) # Increase the form size
$Counter_Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

# Create Labels for countdown and event
$Counter_Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Counter_Label.AutoSize = $true
$Counter_Label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 36, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) # Increase the font size
$Counter_Label.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter # Center the text
$Counter_Label.Text = " " # Add some space
$Counter_Label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Counter_Form.Width / 2 - $Counter_Label.Width / 2), 100) # Center the label

# Create Start button
$Counter_StartButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Counter_StartButton.Text = "Start"
$Counter_StartButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 24, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) # Increase the font size
$Counter_StartButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150, 50) # Set the button size
$Counter_StartButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Counter_Form.Width / 2 - 75), 180) # Adjust the location
$Counter_StartButton.Add_Click({
   # Start the countdown
   StartCountdown
})

# Create Cancel button (initially hidden)
$Counter_CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Counter_CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$Counter_CancelButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 24, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) # Increase the font size
$Counter_CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150, 50) # Set the button size
$Counter_CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Counter_Form.Width / 2 - 75), 180) # Adjust the location
$Counter_CancelButton.Visible = $false # Initially hidden
$Counter_CancelButton.Add_Click({
   # Set a flag to stop the countdown
   $Counter_Form.Tag = $true
   $Counter_CancelButton.Enabled = $false
})

# Create Cancel Script button
$Cancel_ScriptButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Cancel_ScriptButton.Text = "Cancel Script"
$Cancel_ScriptButton.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 24, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold) # Increase the font size
$Cancel_ScriptButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 50) # Set the button size
$Cancel_ScriptButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($Counter_Form.Width / 2 - 100), 260) # Adjust the location
$Cancel_ScriptButton.Add_Click({
   # Close the form and exit the script
   $Counter_Form.Close()
   Exit
})

# Add controls to the form
$Counter_Form.Controls.Add($Counter_Label)
$Counter_Form.Controls.Add($Counter_StartButton)
$Counter_Form.Controls.Add($Counter_CancelButton)
$Counter_Form.Controls.Add($Cancel_ScriptButton)

# Function to start the countdown
function StartCountdown {
   $Counter_Form.Controls.Remove($Counter_StartButton)
   $Counter_Form.Controls.Add($Counter_Label)
   $Counter_Form.Controls.Add($Counter_Event_Label)

   $delay = 60

   while ($delay -ge 0) {
       $Counter_Label.Text = " $($delay)"
       $Counter_Label.Refresh()

       if ($delay -le 5) {
           $Counter_Label.ForeColor = "Red"
           $Counter_Label.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 36, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]([System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold -bor [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Underline))
       }

       Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
       $delay -= 1

       # Check if the user clicked "Cancel"
       if ($Counter_Form.Tag -eq $true) {
           break
       }
   }

   # Re-add the Cancel button after the countdown finishes
   $Counter_Form.Controls.Add($Counter_CancelButton)
}

# Show the form
$Counter_Form.Add_Shown({
   $Counter_Form.Activate()
   # Automatically start the countdown when the form is shown
   StartCountdown
})
$Counter_Form.ShowDialog()
```

Essentially what iam planing on doing with this script is that the user executes it and then it shows a window that says" the computer will restart in x seconds" he then has the option to cancel this or execute it now. But i cant seem to figure out how to make the cancel button clickable. If this has already been answered somehwere pls give me a link to it.

Comment: In short: The two basic options for running code while a WinForms form is being displayed while keeping the form responsive to user input are: (a) Show the form _modally_ (`.ShowDialog()`) and use _event handlers_ for the form's controls to run code. (b) Show the form _non-modally_ (`.Show()`) and enter a loop inside of which you must call `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` periodically in order to keep the form responsive. Both event-handler code and code between `DoEvent()` calls must execute quickly; use jobs for long-running code.
See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: The specific problem is that your `while` loop blocks event-processing by your form, so the event for the cancel button click is never processed. The second linked duplicate has a solution based on a timer control, which avoids this problem.

Comment: The _quickest_ (but not best) way to fix your code is: Replace the `if ($Counter_Form.Tag -eq $true) ...` statement with `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents(); if (-not $Counter_Form.Visible) { break }`.  In your `$Cancel_ScriptButton.Add_Click()` event handler, replace `$Counter_Form.Close()` with `$Counter_Form.Visible = $false` and remove the `exit` statement (it'll cause a crash), and instead handle the exit logic  after the `$Counter_Form.ShowDialog()` call.